# Prove that a continuous function defined on an interval $[a,b]$ has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

I have to prove that :

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ is continuous. Prove that there is at least one fixed point in $[a,b]$.

But I don't know how to attack it since I can't apply anything of uniform continuity or other stuff, I have seen that it is recommended to use Bolzano's theorem but we haven't seen it yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you indicate not having seen the intermediate value theorem, you might want to give some indication of what kinds of facts about continuity you _do_ know about. Just the definition? Which one?

Comment: Well I know the definition the uniformly continuity, and the facts about the compact sets an uni. continuity :)

Comment: So they've defined uniform continuity before mentioning the IVT? What kind of course are you following? Also, did you see anything about ordinary continuity at all? If not, how can you be expected to do exercises about it?

Answer (score 5):

If $f(a)=a$ we are finished. So we can assume that $f(a)\gt a$. Similarly, we can assume that $f(b)\lt b$.

Let $g(x)=x-f(x)$. Then $g(a)\lt 0$, and $g(b)\gt 0$. Also, $g$ is continuous. So by the Intermediate Value Theorem, we have $g(x)=0$ for some $x$ between $a$ and $b$.

**Remark:** In a comment, OP has indicated that the Intermediate Value Theorem has not yet been proved in the course.

One way around the problem is to *prove* the IVT! For guidance, maybe [use this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

A similar proof shows the existence of a fixed point directly. Start by observing that we can assume that $f(a)\gt a$ and $f(b)\lt b$.  Let $S$ be the set of all $x$ in our interval such that $f(x)\gt x$. Then $S$ is non-empty, and bounded above. Thus by the completeness of the reals, $S$ has a supremum $c$. Now show that $f(c)=c$. This can be done by showing that each of $f(c)\gt c$ and $f(c)\lt c$ leads to a contradiction. This is where one uses the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Can we do it with out the mean value thm?

Comment: The Intermediate Value Theorem was used, not the MVT.

Comment: jajajaja I am sorry , with out the IVT

Answer (score 4):

Set $g(x) = f(x) - x$, thus $g(a) \geq 0$ and $g(b) \leq 0$. Also $g$ is 
continious. Now whether $g$ is constant zero function which proof completes or it 
has a negative or positive value in his range. Compare $g(c) < 0$ with $g(a)$ or $g(c) > 0$ with $g(b)$ and conclude (with intermediate value property) that in 
either cases $g$ vanish some where so at that point we must have $f(x) = x$.

If you don't want to use intermediate value theorem you must use this fact that 
$g$ (or any continous function) maps connected sets to connected sets.

Comment: Well we havent seen that to but I think I will stay with the IVT that we have seen in calculus 1 and that will be my argument to the teacher :)

Answer (score 2):

Define the continuous function $g$ by

$$g(x)=f(x)-x$$
and convince yourself that

$$g(a)g(b)\le0$$
and then use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: thnk you but we havent seen the intermediate value thm :)

Comment: Is an introductor course :) I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x)$ be the continuos function , defined from$[a,b]→[a,b]$ and define another function $g(x)$=$x$ , now if $f(a)$ is greater than $a$ and $f(x)$ does not intersect $g(x)$ we can say $f(x)$>$x$ as if it is lesser and it does not intersect with $g(x)$ there will be drop , which creates discontinuity , thus $f(x)$>$x$ for $x$ belonging to [a,b] , but then $f(b)>b$ which creates contradiction , use similar argument for $f(a)<a$