# If $x_{n+1}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}{n}$ then prove or disprove that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function and $x_1\in [0,1]$. If $x_{n+1}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}{n}$ then prove or disprove that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

I have proved

1. If $f$ is constant then the limit exists.
2. $\{(n-1)x_n\}$ is monotonic.
3. By compactness $\{x_n\}$ has limit points

But I am unable to show whether the sequence is monotonic or not and it has one limit point or more than one limit points.

I come to know that a similar question was discussed in the following link

[$f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function. Let $x_1\in[0,1]$ and define $x_{n+1}={\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\over n}$.Prove, $\{x_n\}$ is convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296137/809050)

But some steps in that solution are not clear to me